# 1 VM be connected to 2 VNETS?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, virtual

Sorry if this is vague...I am currently looking at an AZURE architecture design that has 3 VNETs. I am looking for each VNET pass through a firewall server.

Basically I am trying to figure out if 1VM can be part of 3 Virtual networks without multiple NICs, or if AZURE doesn't support this function yet at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A VM can be a part of three subnets in a single network, if you have three nics. So at the minimum you would need an A4/extra large which has a 4 nic capacity.

You could then link the vnets together to create a logical grouping.

But it is not possible to have a single VM in multiple VNets.

Comment: In order to connect the VNets together, look into "VNet Peering"